# Giving gap between rows in angular

Tags: angular, angular8, primeng, angular9

I am using primeng in my angular app. I am using tree table selection with checkbox. code is as follows:

```
<p-toast></p-toast>

<h5>Checkbox Selection</h5>
<p-treeTable
  [value]="files5"
  [columns]="cols"
  selectionMode="checkbox"
  [(selection)]="selectedNodes3"
>
  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <div class="p-d-flex">
      <p-treeTableHeaderCheckbox></p-treeTableHeaderCheckbox>
      <span class="p-ml-2">Toggle All</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
        {{ col.header }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template
    pTemplate="body"
    let-rowNode
    let-rowData="rowData"
    let-columns="columns"
  >
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
        <p-treeTableToggler
          [rowNode]="rowNode"
          *ngIf="i == 0"
        ></p-treeTableToggler>
        <p-treeTableCheckbox
          [value]="rowNode"
          *ngIf="i == 0"
        ></p-treeTableCheckbox>
        {{ rowData[col.field] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>

Component:

import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NodeService} from './nodeservice';
import {TreeNode} from 'primeng/api';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    providers: [MessageService]
})
export class AppComponent { 
     files1: TreeNode[];

    files2: TreeNode[];

    files3: TreeNode[];

    files4: TreeNode[];

    files5: TreeNode[];

    selectedNode1: TreeNode;

    selectedNode2: TreeNode;

    selectedNodes1: TreeNode[];

    selectedNodes2: TreeNode[];

    selectedNodes3: TreeNode[];

    cols: any[];

    constructor(private nodeService: NodeService, private messageService: MessageService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.nodeService.getFilesystem().then(files => this.files1 = files);
        this.nodeService.getFilesystem().then(files => this.files2 = files);
        this.nodeService.getFilesystem().then(files => this.files3 = files);
        this.nodeService.getFilesystem().then(files => this.files4 = files);
        this.nodeService.getFilesystem().then(files => this.files5 = files);

        this.cols = [
            { field: 'name', header: 'Name' },
            { field: 'size', header: 'Size' },
            { field: 'type', header: 'Type' }
        ];
    }

    nodeSelect(event) {
        this.messageService.add({severity: 'info', summary: 'Node Selected', detail: event.node.data.name});
    }

    nodeUnselect(event) {
        this.messageService.add({severity: 'info', summary: 'Node Unselected', detail: event.node.data.name});
    }
}
```

Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetableselection-demo-yxcnnj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

code is working fine. I just want a gap between each row. I tried giving `border-bottom: 3px solid red` . This gives gap between each row but also gives gap in each row when arrow is toggled. I want gap only in outer rows. I don;t want gap in inner rows when arrow is toggled. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

From Your stackblitz I think that the top-level rows will have their property `level` as `0`, right? If yes then you can conditionally add CSS class on Your `<tr>`

For the demo, I created a CSS class in your .css

```
.bottom-border-class {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red !important;
}
```

Then I can use the `[ngClass]` directive to add the CSS only for the top rows *(conditionally)*, by checking if that row's property `level` equals 0, only add border r then.

```
   <tr 
      (click)="nodeSelect(rowNode)"
      [ngClass]="{ 'bottom-border-class': rowNode.level === 0 }"
    >
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
          <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0"></p-treeTableToggler>
          <p-treeTableCheckbox [value]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0"></p-treeTableCheckbox>
          {{ rowData[col.field] }}
      </td>
   </tr>
```

P.S: `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']` was missing in your stackblitz, so you'll have to add it to avoid confusion.

Also you can replace `border-bottom` with `margin-bottom` to only add `gap/space` and not a `border`

### Update:

Stackblitz added

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetableselection-demo-ci31c1?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: there is no property with level 0

Comment: When you click on the row `<tr (click)="nodeSelect(rowNode)">` this fires the method that you created `nodeSelect()` right ? In which you `console.log()` the `rowNode`. In console the data appears to show `{node: {…}, parent: null, level: 0, visible: true…}`. If I expand the row and click the inside rows I get this data in console `{node: {…}, parent: {…}, level: 1, visible: true…}`

Comment: I used this property to apply the `[ngClass]`, does that make sense? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: is it possible for you to update your solution in stackblitz. It will be helpful for me to uderstand

Comment: @Roma, I updated the answer with stackblitz. If you have any further queries ask me.

Comment: if we expand a row is it possible to remove border-bottom of red color for that particular row?

Comment: @Roma, I think you can use the `rowNode.node.expanded` to check if the row is expanded or not. I updated `[ngClass]` logic. It will look something like this. 
 `[ngClass]="{ 'bottom-border-class':  rowNode.level === 0 && rowNode.node.expanded !== true   }"`

Also updated the stackblitz, so you can check that out there too

Comment: I tested it. Problem is when we expand the red color border is getting remove between the expanded element and immediate next main row. in stackblitz if we expand first element "Application", border between "Application" and second element "cloud"is also getting removed. Rest all scenrios are working fine. How can I resolve that?

Comment: @Roma, I think You'll have to style the `last child` of the `expanded node` for that you'll have to add logic to check to find `last child` of the `expanded node`. I suggest reading PRIME-NG's tree table documentation.